# Properties of the inverse normal cdf and permutation probabilities as models for horse racing

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics, inverse-gaussian-distribution

Let $T_i$ be the running time of horse $i$ and $T_i \sim N(\theta_i,1)$ and the $T_i$'s are independent. Then Henery (1981) showed that the probability $P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)$ can be estimated as (taylor expansion to the first degree)
$$P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)|_{\theta=0}+\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \cdot \frac{\partial P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)}{\partial \theta_i}|_{\theta=0}.$$

It is a well known result that $P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)|_{\theta=0} = 1/n!$ by symmetry and that by some calculation that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \cdot \frac{\partial P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)}{\partial \theta_i}|_{\theta=0}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \mu_{1:n},$$
where $\mu_{1:n}$ is the expected value of the $i$-th standard normal order statistic in a sample of size $n$.

Hence $$P(T_1<T_2<\cdots <T_n)\approx \frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \mu_{1:n} \ \ \ \ (*)$$

Then Henery proceeds to say that the RHS or (*) is the same as

$$\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \mu_{1:n} = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1}{n!})+\frac{1}{n!\phi (\Phi^{-1}(\frac{1}{n!}))}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i \mu_{1:n})$$

(where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the normal pdf and cdf respectively) without any calculation and I am puzzled as to how he derived that.

I tried to derive it myself but failed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Reference:
Henery, Robert J. (1981), "Permutation Probabilities as Models for Horse Races." *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B-Methodological* **43**; 86-91.

EDIT: I have run some calculation and it seems that the two are not actually equal but an approximation, but still I have no idea how did Henery derive it.

Comment: There is a statement in this post. It would be a good idea to ask an explicit question wrt the help desired.